# Cloudhub deployment to Business Group failure using Mule Maven Plugin due to access rights to business group

Tags: continuous-integration, mule, maven-plugin, mulesoft, cloudhub

I am trying to deploy Mule application to Business Group in Cloud Hub using Mule Maven Plugin 3.2.7
The Org hierarchy is

```
Fruits
|--oranges
|   |
|   |--dillion
```

I have access to dillion business group only and want to deploy the application to it, but it gives error saying

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy (default-deploy) on project database: Execution default-deploy of goal org.mule.tools.maven:mule-maven-plugin:3.2.7:deploy failed: Please check whether you have the access rights to this business group. -> [Help 1]
```

Below is the cloudhub configuration in POM

```
       <cloudHubDeployment>
                    <username>${username}</username>
                    <password>${password}</password>
                    <environment>${environment}</environment>
                    <applicationName>${application.name}</applicationName>
                    <muleVersion>${mule.version}</muleVersion>
                    <businessGroup>${business.group}</businessGroup>
                </cloudHubDeployment>
```

The maven command to deploy

```
mvn clean package deploy -Dusername=randomuser -Dpassword=randompassword -Denvironment=Sandbox -Dbusiness.group=Fruits\oranges\dillion -Dapplication.name=someapp -Dmule.version=4.2.0 -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DmuleDeploy
```

I've also tried to change the Business group as `Dbusiness.group=oranges/dillion`  , `Dbusiness.group=dillion` and `Dbusiness.group=Fruits/oranges/dillion`

But nothing seems to work.

I've also confirmed that the account I am using to deploy has all the required accesses but it still fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to have access to the parent orgs in order for the businessGroup config to work.

However there is a workaround, you can use businessGroupId instead and pass the ID of the business group ID.

Delete businessGroup and add businessGroupId with the ID instead.

To get you business group of for the sub org follow the instructions here: https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-know-my-Organization-ID-Org-ID-on-the-Anypoint-Platform